# Annoying Firebase Log in Xcode console

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I'm using Google SignIn and Admob via CocoaPods in my current Xcode project.
My pod file looks like this:

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

when I run my project I always get the annoying message from firebase:

> "The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization"

in the project I can see that there are 2 pods "FirebaseAnalytice" and FirebaseCore" are theses sub-pods of the google sign in or the admob pod?

is there a way to hide this message without configure firebase (I won't use it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecated Google pod depends on FirebaseAnalytics. Change your Podfile to directly depend on GoogleSignIn instead of the SignIn subspec in the Google pod:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```